# Exception during the test: Only one entity may be annotated with @RevisionEntity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

i'm trying to audit entities using envers.
I'm using spring boot (2.6.6), hibernate-core (5.6.7.Final) and hibernate-envers (5.6.7.Final).

I have 2 databases postgres and oracle, 2 data sources, and two RevisionEntity, because
I had to extend REVINFO table by user_name. Everything works properly, spring context is created, entity is properly audited with whole data in both databases.

```java
package com.common.revision;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CustomRevisionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int rev;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long revtstmp;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
}
```

```
package com.database.oracle.domain.revision;

@Data
@Entity(name = "REVINFO")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class LegacyRevisionEntity extends CustomRevisionEntity {

}
```

```
package com.database.oracle.domain.revision;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {LegacyRevisionEntity.class},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryOracle",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerOracle")
public class DatastoreConfigurationOracle {
...
```

```
package com.database.postgres.domain.revision;

@Data
@Entity(name = "REVINFO")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionListener.class)
public class ExtensionRevisionEntity extends CustomRevisionEntity {
}
```

```
package com.database.postgres;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {
        BaseModExtensionEntity.class,...  },
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryPostgres",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerPostgres")
public class DatastoreConfigurationPostgres {
...
```

The problem is with one test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class RepositoryTest{

    @Autowired
    Repository repository;

    @Test
    public void find() {


    }
}
```

I've get an error:
entities share the same JPA entity name: [REVINFO] which is not allowed!
So i changed one table name to REV_INFO, so now I'm getting this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Only one entity may be annotated with @RevisionEntity!

I've tried to use @EnableAutoConfiguration with exclude, but it will not working - to many connections with other services.

Any ideas how to fix it and why the application is working while the test fails?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are not using the same `@Configuration` in your test? Try aligning the configurations. Usually, you'll have to assign a persistence unit name to the entity scanning configuration to get multiple `PersistenceUnit` and hence `EntityManagerFactory`, which you can then refer to by name in the repository class. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases for an example